# How to use React ErrorBoundary with redux-observable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, rxjs, redux-observable

React Error Boundaries don't work with asynchronous code.

But I am using `redux-observable` and `rxjs` to fetch my data from my api.

I want to catch the error with the `catchError` function of `rxjs`.

Is it possible to get it work, that I can use an ErrorBoundary for the fetching errors?

Perhaps with the [react-error-boundary](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary) package and the `useErrorHandker` hook? I don't get it to work.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something specific and have decided that you need to handle Rx errors in React error boundaries to achieve what you want, but it may help you more to include some of your code and explain the general outcome you want, rather than asking for a specific implementation. See also: [the X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/566689)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

I already have a config module that I load on startup.

```js
let config: Config = {
  // other config values here
  errorHandler: (error: unknown) unknown => null;
}

export const getConfig = (): Config => config;
export const setConfig = (cfg: Config) => {
  config = cfg;
}
```

Where `Config` is my config interface.

In my top level tsx I do something like:

```js
const errorHandler = useErrorHandler();
setConfig({...getConfig(), errorHandler } );
```

And now, I can access the error handler from my RxJS catchError()

```
catchError((err: unknown) => {
  const errorHandler = getConfig().errorHandler as (e: unknown) => unknown;
  errorHandler(err);
}), ...
```

This works because the module makes the config variable essentially a singleton that is accessible and settable via the exported set/get functions.

I just figured this out last night so some of the typings may need to be adjusted yet, but this is the basic idea.